# AWS - Find out if a security group has a ALL TCP rule through the CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

In the console, you can set a rule with "All TCP" under the "Type" field.  I'm trying to identify this through the CLI, but I'm not finding it in their documentation. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-groups.html
Is it possible to see this?

This is what I've tried:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids <group id>
```

These are the results I get from the command under IPPermissions where I think is where I should see it.

```
 "IpPermissions": [
            {
                "PrefixListIds": [], 
                "FromPort": 0, 
                "IpRanges": [
                    {
                        "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                    }
                ], 
                "ToPort": 65535, 
                "IpProtocol": "tcp", 
                "UserIdGroupPairs": [], 
                "Ipv6Ranges": [
                    {
                        "CidrIpv6": "::/0"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
```

TCP is listed, but I'm specifically looking for a rule that is set to "ALL TCP"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This rule is 'all tcp', because the 'FromPort' is '0' and the 'ToPort' is '65535', in otherwords it is ALL ports.

If, for example, you have a rule for HTTP, it would be 'FromPort:80' and 'ToPort:80',

So you may just need to do a bit more parsing of the results to get the data you want - but the information you need is available in the results you show.